# default value in the function

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, functional-programming

Noticed two patterns to set a default value for an argument of the function:

```
function fn ( val ) {
    val = val || 'default'; // (1)
    val || ( val = 'default' ); // (2)
}
```

Generally I use #1, just found the second one.

which is better? and what is the difference between those? any other options?

Comment: I'll go with with 1st one, second one looks confusing for me atleast.

Comment: 1st one does a reassignment of "val" to either the value of "val" or 'default' if "val" was undefined. 2nd one does an 'hidden if'. val by itself yields the value of val. If it's undefined the or clause get executed (assigning 'default' to val), if it is not undefined, the or clause does not get executed and the value of val is not used anymore.

Comment: Note that neither method is suitable if the function could legitimately be called with a falsy argument value that is different to the default (for example if the default is 1 but you could call it with 0). You asked about other options: much more obvious to newer JS programmers is `if (!val) val = 'default';` or `if (val === undefined) val = 'default';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your methods will not work all the time. If you want to pass `false` as argument for example the expression will be considered false and your variable will be assigned the default value.

For a more robust method you could use:

```
val = typeof val !== 'undefined' ? val : "default";
```

With this method you can pass `false` as argument and even `null` (`typeof null == "object"`)

If you have a lot of optional arguments you could also consider taking an object as parameter and complete it with default values on properties that are not set. This is easier because you can map the value to the property name and the order is not important anymore.